# Cannot read property of state object when testing React component that renders state variable in render

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test a component that has a value from a state object displayed in it's render().

I've simplified the component in question in to this simple Test component for reproduction.  I'm using React 0.12.2.

I am populating my "report" in `getIntitialState's` call to `getStateFromStores()`.  In testing though this value is empty and is what I think is leading to the error.

Certainly a conditional checking to see if `this.state.report` is defined would work, but it seems a bit much to have to put conditionals on all variables printed in a `render()` that are populated via state.

**Test Component**

```
var React = require('react');
var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');

function getStateFromStores() {
  return {
    report: AppStore.getCurrentReport(),
  };
}

var Test = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return getStateFromStores();
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
       <div>
        // This call to the report.id on state seems to be the issue
        {this.state.report.id}
      </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Test;
```

**The Test**

```
jest.dontMock('../Test');
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var Test = require('../Test');

describe("Test", function() {

  it("should render Test", function() {
    var test = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Test />);
    expect(test).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

Ideally, I'd like to pre-populate the state of the component before `renderIntoDocument()` is called in the test as that is where it is failing.

I receive this failure:

```
● Test › it should render Test
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at React.createClass.render            (/Users/kevinold/_development/app/assets/javascripts/_app/components/Test.jsx:20:26)
    at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent     (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:1260:34)
    at wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:50:21)
    at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:802:14)
    at wrapper [as mountComponent] (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:50:21)
    at ReactComponent.Mixin._mountComponentIntoNode (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponent.js:405:25)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.perform (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:134:20)
    at ReactComponent.Mixin.mountComponentIntoNode (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponent.js:381:19)
    at Object.ReactMount._renderNewRootComponent (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:312:25)
    at Object.wrapper [as _renderNewRootComponent] (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:50:21)
    at Object.ReactMount.render (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:381:32)
    at Object.wrapper [as render] (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:50:21)
    at Object.ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/react/lib/ReactTestUtils.js:48:18)
    at Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/kevinold/_development/app/assets/javascripts/_app/components/__tests__/Test-test.js:9:26)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:1065:17)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_   (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2098:31)
    at null._onTimeout (/Users/kevinold/_development/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2088:18)
```

I am not sure how to preload state for this component, which should solve the issue, prior to the `renderIntoDocument()` call in my test.

I've also considered trying to mock `getIntitialState()` for this component, but there has to be a better way.

Any ideas on how to test this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by mocking out the `AppStore.getCurrentReport()` method like so:

```
jest.dontMock('../Test');
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var Test = require('../Test');
var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');

describe("Test", function() {

  it("should render Test", function() {
    // Mock the return value from the method in the store that populates the value in getInitialState()
    AppStore.getCurrentReport.mockReturnValue({id: 1, title: 'Test Rpt'});

    var test = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Test />);
    expect(test).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```